# flutter show open with dialog for map applications

Tags: flutter

I have latitude and longitude of an address in my app. the user needs to route to the address with help from map applications on the device like google maps, waze and etc when a button is pressed.

For example: when I want to load a http link with url_launcher package , when I press the button, a dialog opens that needs me to choose google chrome or firefox, I need something like that for maps applications on the device.

I use the following code to open google maps, but I need it to show a dialogue for the user to choose the preferred app

```
var googleUrl = 'https://www.google.com/maps/search/?api=1&query=${model.beginningLat},${model.beginningLng}';

launch(googleUrl);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code working fine

```
var geo = 'geo:${model.beginningLat},${model.beginningLng}';
launch(geo);
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Do you have any solutions for IOS to show a dialogue for the user to choose the preferred app?